# How do I query a large table of data without encountering errors in my MVC Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have been working on a solution to return specfic data from a database table based on Id's that are passed into the controller.  The data is returned to my KendoUI Grid.  My solution works on tables with small amounts of data, however, on tables with lots of data (over 5000 rows) an error is returned of:

> TypeError: d is null in https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/js/kendo.all.min.js line 25

To get around this problem I tried to implement virtulization, a solutioned offered by the Kendo widget, but the error continues.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyProject.ViewModels.CarViewModel>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns => {
    columns.Select().Width(50);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Id);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
})                    
//Virtulization setting
.Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Virtual(true).Enabled(true))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(100)
    .ServerOperation(true)
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetCars", "Test").Data("myParams"))                        ))
```

Here is my controller.

```
public ActionResult GetCars(int[] array, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
        foreach (var id in array)
        {
            cars.Add(unitOfWork.CarRepository.FindSingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id));
        }
        var result = cars.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Is there a way to handle large portions of data that I query and stop this error?  Just to clarify, if the table doesn't have much data, it works, if it has a lot of data, it doesn't.

**Update**
As per the comment, I attached the unminified version of `kendo.all.js` to see if I could viewmore information.  THe error message remained the same but I can now see the exact line the problem occurs on.

```
getter: function(e, t) {
  var i = e + t;
  return Le[i] = Le[i] || Function("d", "return " + ve.expr(e, t))
},
```

I'm not sure what this actually is, so it doesn't mean anything to me or move my problem forward but it's certainly a start.

**Update**

As per @Richard comment, the `result` contains the following.

```
[0] null
[1] null
[2] {MyProject.Modes.Cars}
```

Comment: Don't think it has to do with volume of data. Maybe try linking to the un-minified version so you can see more info.

Comment: What does `result` contain when debugging the controller and the view component fails ?  When debugging the view does the Network tab show that the expected JSON was delivered by the controller ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Richard, I've added more detail based on what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem was actually in my database.  After @Richard commented about the returned payload I could see that the first two items were null, they shouldnt' have been.  As it turns out the database has been getting work down and the first two id's that I passed in no longer existed.

I adjusted the Id's and the method works without any problems.  Thanks to all for the help and sanity check :)